# Does Unity3D have an app state on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, suspend

On an iOS and/or Android deployed Unity3D based app, what information is available to the app when it resumes after the user suspends it?  Does it continue from where it left off or does the app start from the beginning?

If the app starts from the beginning, is there anything I can take advantage of to restore it's state, or must I manually implement a Memento (pattern)?  Are there any Unity3D events I can subscribe to prepare an app that is being suspended?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have pressed **Play** you have no control over it's building states.

Unity may use it internally when building but it seems to go through all states again when rebuild such as compiling scripts, shader stuff, build versioning, certificate authenticating, build location etc.

These are not valid if you have Unity source and modified build pipeline in your hand. You can implement memento there to check what have changed or not and ignore the state's that have not changed.

These don't have to do anything with game code or events.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, Unity essentially restarts the app from the beginning regardless of any previous "suspended" state on either iOS or Android?  Just as it would start from scratch if you close down the app on Windows or OSX?

Comment: It starts from scratch. On Windows, OSX, iOS build it replaces the existing files if the directory stays same and temp files(all+Android) in Unity replaced for same build ID.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the app stays in memory it will resume after being suspended.

You can use the [`OnApplicationPause (bool)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) to catch when the application is send to the background and do some serialization there. If the app is then removed out of the memory (because the user closed it or the system ran out of memory) you can reload the previous state from this data when the app is restarted.